# PHP read .DBF file in script

Tags: php, dbf

I have a large DBF file that I would simply like to read like a .csv or .txt file by converting it into an array.

```
$file = file_get_contents('data.dbf');
```

Doing this just imports it as one huge blob of text. I tried

`explode("\n\r", $file);`

but that doesn't seem to work either as it treats it like one giant string with no line breaks. Excel btw reads it perfectly.

I don't have the dbase extension installed (not even sure if I can do that easily). Is there any other way I can read it properly line-by-line?

Comment: Try file() instead of file_get_contents(). This creates an array with each element being one line of the file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: I tried that. It still seems to treat it as one giant line.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use dBase [PECL-extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dbase.php) for DBF-files, it allows you to read them properly and separate fields into array.
If you still want to use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) take into account a note from manual:

> If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files
>   either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the
>   auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help
>   resolve the problem.